# Any idea on change the Apple push service certificate in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I went to my production console and changed the certificate as follows

```
prod_app = Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name(APP_NAME_PRODUCTION)
prod_app.certificate = File.read("path/to/new/certificate.pem")
prod_app.save!
```

But It didn't work for me, even I restarted the server and Rpush service.

Now I see this error in Rpush.log

```
[2017-11-09 15:32:57] [ERROR] Rpush::CertificateExpiredError, ios_production certificate expired at 2017-11-09 14:29:24 UTC.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there may be threads which is attached or using the old certificate in the server. so Kill them.

to see all the processors using Rpush, run

```
ps aux | grep rpush
```

And kill the process

```
kill -9 the-pid-number
```

Restart the server

```
bundle exec rpush start -p /home/deploy/pml_prod/shared/tmp/pids/rpush.pid -c /home/deploy/pml_prod/shared/config/rpush.rb -e production
```